# Freeing (vfree-ing) pointer to volatile data

Tags: c, linux-kernel, volatile, vmalloc

`volatile` seems to be a never ending question of every one. I thought I knew everything about it, but then I encountered this:

So, I have a piece of memory shared between threads and I defined it like this:

```
volatile type *name;
```

If it makes you feel better, you can imagine `type` is just an `int`.

This means I have a pointer (that is not volatile) to some data that are volatile. So, for example when it comes to optimizing, the compiler can cache the value of `name` but not `name[0]`. Am I right?

So, now I am `vfree`ing this pointer (it's in a Linux kernel module) and it tells me that `vfree` expects `const void *` while I am passing it `volatile type *`.

I understand how it can be dangerous to pass a `volatile type *` as a `type *` because in that function, the values of `name[i]` could be cached (as a result of optimization) which is not desirable.

I don't understand why though, `vfree` expects me to send it a pointer necessarily to non-volatile data. Is there something I am missing there? Or is it just the guys who wrote `vfree` not thinking about this situation?

I assume me simply casting my pointer to `void *` would not cause any harm, is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My conclusion was that just casting the pointer to `void *` would not cause a problem and the fact that `free` and `vfree` don't directly accept pointers to `volatile` data is just something that was overlooked.

Answer (score 2):

The `vfree` function (and every sane deallocation function in general) does not care about your actual data (be it `volatile` or not). It just expects a (valid) pointer (think: passing the pointer as a `long` value in a CPU register).

Based on that value, the function will:

1. call the SLAB/SLUB to free the memory
2. remove the memory mapping

So yes, casting to a `void *` will not cause any harm at runtime.

Comment: Well yeah, but why doesn't `vfree` accept `volatile type *`? Do you think the coders who wrote that forgot about it or does it actually matter to them?

Comment: I think I agree with Mircea here.  `free()` shouldn't care if the data is volatile or not.  If you're using `volatile` because it's shared memory between tasks, then you had better make sure no one is using it by the time you free it, and then you have nothing to worry about.  If you're using `volatile` because it's memory-mapped I/O, then I'm not sure why you would be freeing.  The `vfree` function doesn't take a `volatile void *` because the "v" in `vmalloc` stands for "virtual", not "volatile".

Comment: @Shahbaz: It does not matter to those developers if the memory you allocated contains volatile data. The vfree() function just needs a pointer to that memory. The developers did not forget anything.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland, I think you are taking me for an idiot! :)) I know what `vmalloc` is and I know no one should be accessing the array when I'm freeing it!! I also don't say `vfree` should care if my data are volatile or not. (read next comment)

Comment: @MirceaGherzan, What I was saying was "Why don't they declare `vfree` as `void vfree(const volatile void *);` so that it accepts both kinds of pointers?" Exactly since the behavior with both types shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Shahbaz:  Didn't mean to offend.  I should hope you knew all that if you're writing kernel code :).  So my best guesses are: 1) To avoid unnecessary restrictions on compiler optimization, 2) because they are declared the same way as `malloc` and `free`, or 3) No one has ever been bothered enough by the compiler warning and/or explicit cast to change it.  Like I said, these are guesses.  I'd be curious if a kernel developer involved in maintaining vmalloc could give a real answer.

Comment: @Shahbaz: Because it would be _wrong_ for them to do so (declare the argument with some extra qualifier(s)). They only provide you with the minimal "interface". It's your job to do the casts. It's also a question of coding "style": think about functions with more pointer arguments and the line length of 80 characters :)

Comment: I don't think it would be _wrong_, because the extra qualifier is in fact making it more general (or maybe I'm wrong, not sure). I do agree with @BrianMcFarland though, seems like it's enough like this, so they never cared. I did try to find the author of `vmalloc` though, and I couldn't find him. You got any clues?

Comment: Adding qualifiers to a value doesn't make it more general, on the contrary. A `const volatile void *` is not really compatible to a `const void *`, nor vice versa. Using `const`, `volatile` and `restrict` (C99), eight differently qualified variables can be declared. In your case, the `const` for the `vfree` parameter just indicates that the `vfree` function doesn't change the value pointed at. Therefore you may fearlessly cast you pointer to `void *`, the additional `volatile` is irrelevant, since the value is not changed (or even used) by the `vfree` function. Or do you still expect problems?